# Modify array object by async method under async forEach loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, typescript, foreach, callback

First of all, I have an array of `users` that contains some basic data, such as

`{"id": "1", "name": "a" }, {"id": "2", "name": "b" }`

Now by calling a remote API: `self.getDrinks` for each `user.id`, it returns a new array `drinks[]`. Then I want to integrate the `drinks` into each user, finally it should be:

`{"id": "1", "name": "a", "drinks": [{"id": "1-1", "name": "coke"}, {"id": "1-2", "name": "orange"}]}, {"id": "2", "name": "b", "drinks": [{"id": "2-1", "name": "coke"}, {"id": "2-2", "name": "lime"}] }`

I used noSQL so that I have to do async functions to resolve return data:

```
Result {
  result (object, optional),
  message (string, optional),
  error (integer, optional)
}
```

So here is my function:

```
var self = this;
var itemsProcessed = 0;

this.users.forEach(function (user, idx, arr) {

  //assume the API getDrinks needs more parameters like below

  self.getDrinks(user.id, "getDrink", 0, 100, '', '', '', '', '') 
    .then((data: Result) => {
      itemsProcessed++;
      arr[idx].drinks = data.result.drinks;            
      }
      if (itemsProcessed === arr.length) {
        Logger.debug("Expected Result: " + JSON.stringify(arr));
      }
    })
    .catch(reason => Logger.error(reason));
});

Logger.debug("UnExpected Result: " + JSON.stringify(this.users));
```

As you can see, finally I cannot get correct `this.users` since it is modified in `then` function under forEach.

Some people suggest me to use `Promise.all()` but it always reports syntax error due to the return type is an array `drinks[]`

Comment: the users will be changed, just not when you log them

Comment: @JaromandaX It only prints the same original `users` without `drinks[]`. And the 2nd Logger will be executed before the 1st Logger, so the users will not have drinks[] in the end.

Comment: my point was that users **are** modified, just not at the point you log `this.users` - you state that they *will not be changed* - which is incorrect

Comment: Thanks, @JaromandaX, I modify my question.

Answer (score 1):

Using promise.all you should be able to simplify your code to the following:

```
Promise.all(this.users.map((user, idx, arr) => 
    this.getDrinks(user.id, "getDrink", 0, 100, '', '', '', '', '') 
    .then((data: Result) => {
        itemsProcessed++;
        user.drinks = data.result.drinks;            
    })
    .catch(reason => Logger.error(reason))
))
.then(() => Logger.debug("UnExpected Result: " + JSON.stringify(this.users)));
```

Comment: As our `drinks` type is an array. That code will give syntax error: `Argument type Promise<TResut>[] is not assignable to parameter type iterableShim<PromiseLike<T>|T>`

Comment: is that a typescript limitation on what a promise can resolve to?

Comment: I get this from Github: [link](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts) But I think it should support common types

Comment: If there's a problem with an array and promises that's irrelevant to this as any promises are unaware of the data type of drinks. Look at the code.

Comment: okay, as it returns an error what you could think of the problem is? I think type `Promise<TResult>[]` is to say some `[]` returned to `Promise` during mapping before it converted to any other type which `iterableShim` may accept.